# Reading value from data row

Tags: c#

Is it possible to read a value from a data row?

I have this code:

```
bool CatchweightItem;
if (dr_art_line["CatchweightItemt"].ToString() -> READ VALUE)
{
    CatchweightItem = false;
}
else
{
    CatchweightItem = true;
}
```

So I am wondering if it is possible to read a value of that field. If the value is `false`, set variable to `false` and if it's true set variable to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool CatchweightItem = Convert.ToBoolean(dr_art_line["CatchweightItemt"].ToString());
```

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean.aspx)

Comment: Thats it? But what's with if function, I need it to set value in varibale  CatchweightItem, the field that is beein red can be true or false and I need to reed that value

Comment: @Bruno `dr_art_line["CatchweightItemt"].ToString()` This line reads your string and `Convert.ToBoolean` will convert that string to bool value. whether your value is TRUE or true or TRue or TRUe it will assign CatchweightItem with true and if value is FALSE or False or false it will assign false to CatchweightItem. Test it. I have tested and used it n number of times.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the == operator to check the value like so:

```
bool CatchweightItem;
if (dr_art_line["CatchweightItemt"].ToString() == "FALSE")
{
    CatchweightItem = false;
}
else
{
    CatchweightItem = true;
}
```

Actually, you don't need all that code, you can also do this much shorter and cleaner:

```
bool CatchweightItem = (dr_art_line["CatchweightItemt"].ToString() == "TRUE")
```

Comment: But what if value is TrUe or FalSe or tRue or falsE or there are n number of ways this value is stored. In your case either use `.ToLower()` or `ToUpper()`  or just `Convert.ToBoolean` which just checks for all possible values of string

Comment: You are wright, but the value is comming from xml document, and we aggred that it will write "false"

Answer (score 1):

If the DataColumn's [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) is `bool` anyway, you should use this strong-type method:

```
bool isCatchweightItem = dr_art_line.Field<bool>("CatchweightItemt");
```

[`DataRowExtensions.Field<T>` Method (DataRow, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx)

It also supports nullable types.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(string.Compare(Convert.ToString(dr_art_line["CatchweightItemt"])+"","false",true)==0)
         { 
CatchweightItem = false; }
 else {  
CatchweightItem = true; }
```

This will avoid null value coming from database as well as case insensitive check.